# How to dynamically change the document structure, merge into an array from a scalar value?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I have a collection of documents:

```
{"name":1,"b":3,"c":3}
{"name":1,"b":3,"c":5}
{"name":1,"b":3,"c":6}
{"name":2,"b":6,"c":6}
{"name":2,"b":6,"c":7}
{"name":2,"b":6,"c":3}
{"name":3,"b":2,"c":3}
{"name":4,"b":2,"c":3}
```

I would like to merge the collection into the following result:

```
{"name":1,"b":3,"c":[3,5,6]}
{"name":2,"b":6,"c":[6,7,3]}
{"name":3,"b":2,"c":3}
{"name":4,"b":2,"c":3}
```

Which means eliminating duplicate documents and save their `c` fields as an array. `c` would then be an array.

Notes: the first(e.g. "name") and second(e.g"b") fields are unique per document.

```
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
       DBObject currentObject = cursor.next();
       String currentName = (String)currentObject.get("name");
        if (currentName.equals(previousName) && !previousName.equals(""))
        {
            // what should i write here 
            collection.remove(previousObject);
        }
        previousObject = currentObject;
        previousName = (String)previousObject.get("name");
    }
```

Comment: You could just a List implementation, and construct an array from it.

Answer (score 1):

You can hold a map of names and `DBObjects` and `push` into the value as you progress, something like this:

```
    Map<String,DBObject> names = new HashMap<String, DBObject>();
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        DBObject currentObject = cursor.next();
        String currentName = (String) currentObject.get("name");
        DBObject o = names.get(currentName);
        if (o!=null) { //means you already have it.
            Integer c = (Integer) currentObject.get("c");
            collection.remove(currentObject);
            collection.update(o,new BasicDBObject("$push",new BasicDBObject("c",c)));
        }else {
            names.put(currentName,currentObject);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about MongoDB, but as naimdjon said you'll need some map.
Here is a generic Java solution to your problem:

A class to simulate your input

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


public class SomeDbObject {
    Integer name;
    Integer b;
    Set<Integer> c;


    public SomeDbObject(Integer name, Integer b, Integer c){
        this.name = name;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = new HashSet<>();
        this.c.add(c);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return c.toString();
    }
}
```

And now a test class with your data set (use name and b as your "keys"):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.junit.Test;


public class SomeDbObjectTest {

    @Test
    public void testProblem(){

        List<SomeDbObject> l = new ArrayList<SomeDbObject>();
        l.add(new SomeDbObject(1,3,3));
        l.add(new SomeDbObject(1,3,5));
        l.add(new SomeDbObject(1,3,6));
        l.add(new SomeDbObject(2,6,6));
        l.add(new SomeDbObject(2,6,7));
        l.add(new SomeDbObject(2,6,3));
        l.add(new SomeDbObject(3,2,3));
        l.add(new SomeDbObject(4,2,3));

        Map<Integer,Map<Integer,SomeDbObject>> m = new HashMap<Integer,Map<Integer,SomeDbObject>>();

        for(SomeDbObject tc : l){
            Map<Integer,SomeDbObject> mTc = m.get(tc.name);

            if(mTc == null){
                mTc = new HashMap<Integer,SomeDbObject>();
                mTc.put(tc.b, tc); 
                m.put(tc.name, mTc);
            } else {
                SomeDbObject alreadyExistingRec = mTc.get(tc.b);
                alreadyExistingRec.c.addAll(tc.c);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the aggregation framework using the below query in shell:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$group:{_id:{name:"$name", b:"$b"}, c:{$addToSet:"$c"}}}, 
{$project:{_id:0, name:"$_id.name", b:"$_id.b", c:1}}
])
```

This query can be translated to Java.